# Applet Initialization. Unable to Get Stream Input

Tags: java, html, applet

currently working on a simple test game that I am trying to implement into a webpage. The game works fine in eclipse and has no problem launching. However after going through the perilous process of signing all the JARs and getting the requires libraries to load I have hit a dead end.

Here is the HTML File I am using to load the JAR files.

```
<applet code="org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader" archive="lwjgl_util_applet.jar" codebase="." width="800" height="600">
    <param name="al_title" value="botGame">
    <param name="al_main" value="BRANDON.GameApplet">
    <param name="al_jars" value="game.jar, lwjgl.jar">
    <param name="al_logo" value="">
    <param name="al_windows" value>
    <param name="al_windows" value="native-win32.jar">
    <param name="al_linux" value="natives-linux.jar">
    <param name="al_mac" value="natives-mac.jar">
    <param name="al_progressbar" value="">
</applet>
```

I signed all of these JARs so that shouldn't be the problem, but it gives me this error when loading.

```
This occurred while 'Downloading packages'
Unable to get input stream for native-win32.jar
java.lang.Exception: Unable to get input stream for native-win32.jar
    at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader.getJarInputStream(AppletLoader.java:1256)
    at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader.downloadJars(AppletLoader.java:1146)
    at org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader.run(AppletLoader.java:753)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you developing this project in a Windows environment and testing in a non-Windows environment?

Comment: Are you integrating with [flowpaint](http://code.google.com/p/flowpaint/)?

Comment: I am developing in windows and testing in windows. 

I am not using flowplaint

Comment: these are native jars? what does that mean?

Comment: those are the LWJGL library binaries that I stored in a jar

Comment: @Brandon did you solve the issue ? if yes how ?